# Agregagate mongo subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection of documents

```
_id: 'ObjectId(SomeID),
order_number: Some#,
products: [
    {name: 'SomeName',
    price: SomePrice},
    {name: 'SomeName',
    price: SomePrice},
    {name: 'SomeName',
    price: SomePrice}
]
```

I'm looking for a way to get an array of objects containing all the sold products and the info of the order, something like this:

```
[{
    _id: 'ObjectId(SomeID),
    order_number: Some#,
    name: 'SomeName',
    price: SomePrice}
 },
 {
    _id: 'ObjectId(SomeID),
    order_number: Some#,
    name: 'SomeName',
    price: SomePrice}
 }]
```

Is it possible using the function agreggate or something else?

Comment: I don't understand, have you tried using [`Collection.aggregate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#aggregate) or not?

Comment: @zero298 not really, I was looking at the documentation and did not found what I was looking for. Maybe I didnt understood it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I used

```
collection.aggregate([{$unwind: '$products'}], function(error, result){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return callback(error, 'Error.');
    }
    return callback(null, result);
});
```